# An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012

On the time process with program visual studio. I have exception

**An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll but was not handled in user code**

My code :
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load("gfx/actor.xml");

My actor.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <!-- TODO: replace this Asset with your own XML asset data. -->
  <Asset Type="System.String"></Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. 
Thank all

Comment: Read the message or inner exception.

Comment: Hi SLaks,
This message is title of question. I saw on debug also show this message.

Comment: That's VS telling you that an exception was thrown.  You need to use the debugger to see what the exception actually _is_.

Comment: Hi , Please help me to resolve problem. I tried to fix it but not any result. I hope that from your help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to read the exception message and find out what the problem is.